# Edge Side Includes (ESI) are anything like Facebook's BigPipe?

Tags: facebook, performance, web-applications, symfony, esi

Everyone interested in web application performance knows about the idea behind [Facebook's BigPipe](https://www.facebook.com/note.php?note_id=389414033919).

Recently, Symfony released a new feature, called the [fragments sub-framework](http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-2-the-new-fragment-sub-framework).

The idea behing this feature is to use the ESI technology, described to W3C as the [ESI Language Specification 1.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/esi-lang).

My question is: is Facebook's BigPipe in any way related to this ESI technology? Can I achieve the BigPipe idea using ESI?

Comment: Why the downvotes? This is a perfectly valid question, as it sounds _on the surface_ like the same thing—delivering parts of the page at different times, etc. Thanks for asking!

Answer (score 4):

Probably not without your own ESI server implementation, and even then it's questionable whether it's worth the performance hit.

Assuming I understand that BigPipe article correctly, all the server-side has to do is a) immediately flush some static HTML content to the client and b) asynchronously start a few rendering threads and flush the output whenever a thread has finished rendering. The rest is javascript magic and has nothing to do with the server-side framework.

Symfony is able to render a simple HTML document and include ESI tags therein, so a) is covered. But ESI is dependent on the order in which the tags are encountered. This means that while I suppose most cache servers will start processing all ESI tags asynchronously, they can only flush the output in a specific order. This, in turn, means that if your first ESI tag is slow, it will prevent any other "pagelet" from being flushed to the user.

This is why I believe you'd need a special kind of caching server that can asynchronously fetch includes while *completely ignoring* where in the document they appear.

The other major drawback is that each ESI tag would cause its own HTTP request to symfony which has a pretty huge setup overhead for each request.

In conclusion: ESI is great if you want to return a cached page that's expensive to generate with a tiny bit of un-cacheable content, but it's probably not a good fit for implementing BigPipe.